# Reason behind Chrome not running in root user in kali Linux?

Tags: chrome, kali-linux, root

Why does Google Chrome not run as root user by default in Kali Linux? Is it a security issue?

Comment: Quick question for you - do you think it should run as root? What implications would that have?

Comment: @RoryAlsop I do not see how this answered their question. Given they are a new user, they may also be new to the dangers of root. Particularly running graphical applications as root, and the dangers of privilege escalation.

Comment: Safesploit - what do you mean? I certainly didn't try to answer the question. I commented, specifically asking them to consider something.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I just feel the number of downvotes towards this question to be unreasonable, as it asks a valid question. Which despite research looking for a duplicate question, the general theme I came across doing this was 'don't run web browsers as root' without giving clear reasons. I am curious myself to why the developers put these safeguards in place, to begin with, while others have not. Particularly when I found quite simple bypasses.

Comment: I wonder why somebody would ever need to run a browser as root. Are there any cases when this would make sense?

Comment: @reed No. The problem is that Kali is not designed to be secure, and so runs _everything_ as root by default whenever it can. People who use Kali in this way are just asking to get pwnt.

Comment: @safesploit my assumption is the down views are because least privilege is a very well understood basic premise of security and the OP maybe hadn't done sufficient research.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically because of the principle of least privilege (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). There is no reason to give Chrome all the power and capabilities that root has. More privileges mean more trouble in case something goes wrong.

As a side note I have to say though, that I am skeptical about the advantages of low privileges in the specific case a typical Linux desktop gets compromised, because the typical desktop user regularly uses `sudo` to basically get *all* the privileges. The user just trusts sudo, but sudo is just meant to be used for convenience, not for real security, because it doesn't provide enough separation of privileges. But this is a side note, regarding a specific issue. In general the principle of least privilege *always* applies.

Comment: Even with bad use of `sudo`, low privileges can still be beneficial. For example, imagine a malicious process is executed while the user is doing something sensitive (transferring all their Bitcoins or whatever), and only later do they use `sudo` in a way that lets the process get root. By the time it gets root, it may be too late.